# Laravel HTMLPurifier

Tags: laravel, htmlpurifier

I'm having a problem getting the HTMLPurifier bundle to work. I installed is as so:

```
php artisan bundle:install Sanitizer
```

then I edited application/bundles.php

```
'sanitize' => array('auto' => true),
```

when I use it:

```
$clean_output = Sanitize::purify($bad_input);
```

I get an Unhandled Exception: *Class 'Sanitize' not found*

I also noticed that when I try: php artisan bundle:upgrade Sanitize, 
I get an error saying bundle not installed.
What am I missing?
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bundle has been setup very badly, especially with the different namings and casings. Generally a bundle uses a standard name across the board. What's happening here is that when you install the bundle it's actually installing it to `bundles/laravel-htmlpurifier`. What you've defined in your `bundles.php` file is expecting it to be installed at `bundles/sanitize`.

You have two options.

#### Option 1

Rename the `laravel-htmlpurifier` directory to `sanitize`.

#### Option 2

Set the `location` key in the `bundles.php` file.

```
'sanitize' => array('auto' => true, 'location' => 'laravel-htmlpurifier')
```

This should also resolve the upgrading problems you were having. You shouldn't really have to do this as it's normally the responsibility of the bundle author to ensure everything is named correctly and consistently.

Comment: Thanks so much, was pulling my hair out trying to get it to work.